# Return multiple values from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter

How could I filter through each array in this array to grab only certain pieces of data such as `tid`, `uid` and `device`?

I have used `array_column` to get only one piece of information but how could I get multiple ones?

```
$object = $ticket->find();
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
var_dump($arr);
```

The snippet of code above is what returns the array of data.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'tid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '22' (length=2)
      'subject' => string 'iPhone 8' (length=8)
      'issue' => string 'iPhone 8 screen replacement' (length=27)
      'device' => string 'iPhone 8' (length=8)
      'created' => string '2017-05-25 00:01:11' (length=19)
      'identifier' => string '29cd54bf' (length=8)
      'status' => string 'New' (length=3)
      'tech' => string 'None' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'tid' => string '2' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '22' (length=2)
      'subject' => string 'iPhone 7' (length=8)
      'issue' => string 'iPhone 7 screen replacement' (length=27)
      'device' => string 'iPhone 7' (length=8)
      'created' => string '2017-05-25 00:27:42' (length=19)
      'identifier' => string 'b47f2c82' (length=8)
      'status' => string 'New' (length=3)
      'tech' => string 'None' (length=4)
```

**Expected output:**

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1"
        [1]=> string(2) "22"
        [2]=> string(8) "iPhone 8"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2"
        [1]=> string(2) "22"
        [2]=> string(8) "iPhone 7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Dunno what you're using but doesn't the `find()` method or something prior to the find allow you to limit the columns that are returned?

Comment: I know this is quite old, but in case anyone comes across it https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php is a good solution, particularly if your arrays might be dynamic.  Array intersect will return the entries that are in both your master array and the array(s) to compare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we are using `array_map` to achieve desired output.

**Solution 1:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805319)

```
$array=array_map(function($value){
    return array($value["tid"],$value["uid"],$value["subject"]);
},$array);
print_r($array);
```

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805327)

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $result[]=array($value["tid"],$value["uid"],$value["subject"]);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you Sahil. I was looking up array_map in the php documentation but was having trouble implementing that with my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @TrentonTyler Can you share your piece of code in your post, so that i can help you with that as well. you can change `$array` of my post with `$arr`

Comment: For that you can use `HTML table `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145149/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-trenton-tyler).

Comment: Let us chat @SahilGulati

Comment: I am in chat at the moment.

Comment: @TrentonTyler I have posted a link which will helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map`,

```
array_map(function($v){return [$v['tid'], $v['uid'], $v['device']];}, $array);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a double `foreach` loop to go through and then print out the values which you like.

```
foreach ($arr as $ar) {
    foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'tid' | $key == 'uid' | $key == 'device') {
            echo $key . ': ' . $value;
        }
    }
}
```